# ShiningPanda Virtualenv Builder Shell Script returning incorrect error code

Tags: python, bash, shell, jenkins, setuptools

I have a Jenkins job that runs a virtualenv with ShiningPanda's Virtualenv Builder. In this virtualenv it executes this shell script with options `-xe`:

```
pip install setuptools
python setup.py sdist upload -r http://jenkins:${PYSHOP_PASS}@localhost:8000/simple/
```

That url is intentionally wrong, to verify that the build fails when the sdist push fails. It should return `1`.

This returns a status code of `0`. Why? It only happens when using Python 3.4. It behaves correctly in Python 2.7. It also behaves correctly on my local machine in Python 3.4 and Python 3.5. What gives?

I have tried running with sh and bash. I have tried with a few different flags. What gives?

Comment: What should it be returning? Is something failing?

Comment: Excellent point. I left that out. It is an intentionally erroneous url. Updated.

Comment: Try using `set -o pipefail` at the begin of your script.

Comment: This is tagged bash, but it has to be a python issue :(

Comment: What is your python here? Could be it is some wrapper script? Try `file $(readlink -f $(which python))` /